# TSQL Generate Unique Datetime values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I´m trying to generate unique datetime values for a set of legacy values. Unfortunately the GETDATE() call is only evaluated once, which results in the same datetime for each row.

```
UPDATE e
SET e.moddate = GETDATE()
FROM dbo.entries as e
```

Does anyone know how it would be possible to delay the single inserts or how to evaluate the GETDATE() call multiple times?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the table have any other numeric field?

Comment: You want the insert DateTime to be unique for each row? If so, don't do that, just use an `uniqueidentifier` or `int`

Comment: use a column id (int identity). if you combine this column with the date column you will get unique value.

Comment: The subquery didn´t work. There are other numeric values present but none of them are unique. Unfortunately i have to use the date as an id.

Comment: Are there any other unique columns at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
;with cte as
(select *,row_number() over (partition by getdate() order by getdate()) rn from entries)

 update entries
 set [moddate] = dateadd(second,rn,getdate())
 from entries e
 inner join cte c on e.col1 = c.col1
```

This will work as long as you have another column called `col1`, regardless of uniqueness.

Demo [here](http://rextester.com/DRUO31026).

Comment: That works for all entries where there is a unique value, but generates the same date for each row where the same col1 value is present.

Comment: I can't see that in my demo. Did you check my demo link? Also, do you want different **date** or different **datetime**?

Comment: I want a different datetime.

Comment: Ok i added an additional value to rn which is seemingly random enough to generate unqiue values.

Answer (score 1):

You need to generate some sort of formula to do this. System don't know by what logic you want to go to find unique date.

If I would you I would do something like this

```
update e set e.moddate = DateAdd(second, 1, (select max(moddate) from dbo.entries)) FROM dbo.entries as e where e.id != 1
```

Here system will pick the last highest date and add 1 second to it, now, what I do is I enter one record that is TOTAL Record count - Now(), as date, so the last record get today's time. and this way I get unique datetime for each record.

Comment: It is still a single sql statement. As such the DateAdd value is only evaluated once and not per single insertion.

Answer (score 0):

```
with C as
(
  select e.moddate,
         row_number() over(order by 1/0) as s
  from dbo.entries as e
)
update C
set C.moddate = dateadd(second, C.s, getdate())
```